# Date attribute in Db schema

Tags: database, database-normalization

**A question I got in my last interview:**

> You are given a Database of Employee details containing a id and date of joining column. Is the table in 1NF?

I was wondering if with date attribute, whether the schema can be in 1NF or not. How would the existence of date change the answer?

Comment: Its a trick question, date has nothing to do with normalization.

Comment: time field as a primary key?

Answer (score 0):

The whole Idea of the question was to **trick you** **into thinking Date is not a 1NF column.**

1NF specifies that all attributes store atomic values. Codd defines an atomic value as one that "*cannot be decomposed into smaller pieces by the DBMS*"[7] meaning a **column should not be divided into parts with more than one kind of data** in it such that what one part means to the DBMS depends on another part of the same column.

Simply put there should not be 2 values in the attribute of a single tuple.

This table does not satisfy 1NF. Because there are multiple phone numbers in a column.

```
Customer ID     First Name  Surname     Telephone Number
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
123             Pooja       Singh       555-861-2025, 192-122-1111
456             San         Zhang       (555) 403-1659 Ext. 53; 182-929-2929
789             John        Doe         555-808-9633
```

To make the given table in 1NF we seperate the telephone number column into 2 seperate columns.

```
Customer ID     First Name  Surname     Telephone Number1   Telephone Number2
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
123             Pooja       Singh        555-861-2025       192-122-1111
456             San         Zhang        (555) 403-1659     Ext. 53 182-929-2929
789             John        Doe          555-808-9633
```

Unlike the 1st table **as long as you store only 1 date, in a single column, your table will be in 1NF.**